# Trying to understand Timestamps and Timezones in PHP

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp

I have a PHP application that needs to support timezones. Now I am storing date and time values in the database as integers. So here is what I do.

```
// now create the DateTime object for this time and user time zone
$dtime = new DateTime($date_time, new DateTimeZone($time_zone));
$timestamp = $dtime->format('U');
```

What I don't understand is even if the person is in New Zealand (Pacific/Auckland) and the application stores this date: 24-12-2010 00:00:00 using the above code the value comes back as: 1293102000

Then using the exact same date/time and setting the time zone to London (Europe/London) I get this timestamp:1293148800

Why are the timestamps different? I thought the timestamp would be the same number of seconds as its the same date from the Unix Epoch?

If they are different that means when someone is searching the database for all records between 24-12-2010 00:00:00 and 24-12-2010 23:59:59 I need to use the users timezone for the creation of the timestamps and I must use the timezone to firstly create the timestamps.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Because timezone for New Zealand is +1300 UTC, where London is zero UTC, `13 x 3600seconds = 1293148800-1293102000`

Since you already store as integer, you should <strike>always use zero UTC</strike> skip timezone when you construct `$dtime`

For testing

```
# date_create is procedural style
$obj =  date_create('24-12-2010 00:00:00', new DateTimeZone('europe/london'));
echo $obj->format('U');

$obj =  date_create('24-12-2010 00:00:00');
echo $obj->format('U');
```

Comment: Quote from php.net: `Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)`, so the `format("U")` should return a GMT timestamp, regardless of the timezone.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Can you explain a little bit more on "you should always use zero UTC when you construct $dtime" are you saying I need to create timestamps without the timezone?

Comment: So my code should be:
$dtime = new DateTime('24-12-2010 00:00:00');
$timestamp = $dtime->format('U');

Comment: @Marc - Yup, I think is incorrect to use the term "zero UTC", it should just `$dtime = new DateTime($date_time);`, can you do a test for verification?

Comment: $dtime = new DateTime('24-12-2010 00:00:00'); $timestamp = $dtime->format('U');
=> 1293102000

Comment: Then if this is the case when converting a date say "24-12-2010 13:34:59' to a timestamp you do not use a timezone and converting the timestamp back to a date would not require a timezone either. So maybe you only really need timezones when you need to say convert the date and time to another timezone to find the local time for that date/time?

Comment: You can use timezone, always set & get should using a consistent way. So, calculate timezone difference will be consistent.

Comment: Here is my issue - the server which runs the code is in the USA and my clients are in New Zealand so if they set an automated task that my application needs to execute say at 4pm NZT then my code needs to run that job not on the USA 4pm time on when its 4pm in New Zealand.

Comment: Two possible solutions, **1.** stored as UTC not integer **2.** add a column to store the UTC offset, and use column+UTC for the automated task

Comment: Hello - is it possible to provide an example code for options 1 and 2? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Marc - I think that should be a new question instead